# i want to reverse my date column from '26-01-2016' to '2016-01-26' format

Tags: mysql, date

i want to reverse my date column from '26-01-2016' to '2016-01-26' format.please suggest me the solution for this question.the formate of my date column is 'DD-MM-YYYY' and i want it to be 'YYYY-MM-DD' in mysql

Comment: try date_format (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%m.%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: When it's in the format the OP specified, it's no date, therefore date_format() doesn't work. You have to use str_to_date().